# Error: npm ERR! grpc@1.10.3 install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

when shrinkwrap is overriding package.json  I am getting this error

npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!/Users/Saeef/.npm/_logs/2018-06-18T13_15_02_412Z-debug.log

Comment: Is that possibly a duplicate of this one here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo